# Determine if the following geometric series convers or diverges. If it converges, what is it's sum?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, geometric-series

Determine if the following geometric series converges or diverges. If it converges, what is its sum?
$$\sum_{i=0}^n  \frac{1}{(\sqrt[]{2})^n}$$

So I know that it converges because $$r =\frac{1}{(\sqrt[]{2})}$$

The answer is $$ 2 + \sqrt[]{2}$$

I have no idea how they got there. Can anybody help?

Comment: $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}r^n = \frac{1}{1-r}$ whenever $|r|<1$. Here $r=1/\sqrt{2}$ so $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1-1/\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}-1}=2+\sqrt{2}$

Comment: @M. Boyet , my textbook only has the formula $$\sum_{i=1}^n  = \frac{a}{(1-r)}$$ , How would I go about converting it to that form? I think that's why I'm confused. I was trying to find a and I came up with 1/sqrt(2)

Comment: The $\Sigma$ symbol you just gave shouldn't end at $n$ but should go to $\infty$

Comment: $(1-r)\sum_{j=0}^nr^j=1-r^{n+1}.$... E.g.$\;(1-r)(1+r+r^2)=$ $(1+r+r^2)-r(1+r+r^2)=$ $(1+r+r^2)-(r+r^2+r^3)=1-r^3$.... So if $r\ne 1$ then $\sum_{j=0}^nr^j=\frac {1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}.$

Answer (score 2):

Formula for sum of G.P. with infinite terms ,

$$S_{\infty}=\frac{a}{1-r}$$

Where $a$ is the first term of series and $r$ is common ratio. ($|r|<1$)

In your case :

$$S_{\infty}=\frac{1}{(\sqrt2)^0}+\frac{1}{(\sqrt2)^1}+\frac{1}{(\sqrt2)^2}+\frac{1}{(\sqrt2)^3} \dots \infty$$

Since $(\sqrt2)^0=1$

$$S_{\infty}=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+\frac{1}{(\sqrt2)^2}+\frac{1}{(\sqrt2)^3} \dots \infty$$
 $$a=1 ~~~~\text{and}~~~~ r=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$

$$S_{\infty}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}} =\frac{\sqrt2}{{\sqrt2}-1} \times \frac{{\sqrt2}+1}{{\sqrt2}+1}=2+{\sqrt2}$$

Comment: How did you get a = 1. ? That's what I've been using but I ended up with a and r being equal.

Comment: I could not figure out how to get the series in the form of ar^(n-1)

Comment: @cicero866 Is it okay now?

Comment: I think so! Thank you!